# There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code InternalServerError in web chat bot framework azure portal

Tags: azure, botframework

I am trying to test the sample application listed in BOT builder for .NET - Getting Started

I have created web app luis bot using arm template in Azure. My website works fine but when I start to chat, it gives error message 'could not send..retry' in channel blade.

There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code InternalServerError:

[image]

I have updated MSAppId and password in web.config file that also not working 
[image]

Anybody please suggest me if i need to add any steps

Comment: Do you have app insights setup with your bot? One thing to try when you publish your bot from Visual Studio is to go to the publish settings and there should be an option to remove additional files at the destination. Try that and see if that fixes it.

Comment: When on the WebChat view, press [Ctrl Shift I] to open your browser console. Do you see any error details that might explain what's wrong with the bot? Does your bot work locally when you run it using the [Emulator](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator)? Using the Emulator is a useful way to test your bot (and see errors) before deploying.  If either of these give you further error details, edit your post with those and we'll try to help out. :)

Comment: Would you please install ngrok and tunnel your endpoint to localhost so you can debug what exception is your bot throwing? Let me know if you can do this or if you need further assistance

Comment: @kjr1995 i have created the bot using arm template with azure powershell and application insight also working fine

Comment: @Corina im working in operational level ,so i didn't have option to work with emulator ,i need to resolve this through azure portal with arm template please help me out how to acheive this

Comment: @TheMemebot could you please tell me how to use this ngrok in my bot app

Comment: @JACK try this please https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TiOGGUgN5_c

Comment: You can also set up [continuous deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-build-continuous-deployment?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) in order to debug your deployed bot locally.

Comment: @JACK are you still having trouble? If you are, please feel free to email me your bot handle and Microsoft App id to v-corgum@microsoft.com. I can take a look at it and see if there is more information that could help us solve your problem.

Comment: @Corina I have resolved the issue,its because of the api endpoint connectivity with luis ,my bot is working fine thanks for understanding,thank you everyone

Comment: Hi guys ,any of tried to create SDK V4 Bot using ARM Template via Azure Powershell

Answer (score 2):

I followed [the document](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/57.teams-conversation-bot) to download the sample and create the bot but when I run the program and `ngrok` in local environment and test in the webchat, it reported 500 `Internal Server Errors`.

I found the console information:

> 'Application with identifier 'cxxxx5' was not found in the directory 'botframework.com'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.'

So I tried to manage the Azure AD application as a Multitenant app. And it worked.

Comment: making Supported account types , multitenant , has just fixed my error! thank you for mentioning that. I was pulling my hair :D